# How do I enter a flipped toeplitz matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, toeplitz

What is a clean way to use vector *a* to make matrix *A* in matlab? Notice that the bottom right corner is padded with ones. Sometimes I will want to pad it with something else, like zeros.

```
% use this vector
a = [4, 2, 5, 6]

% to make this matrix
A = [
    4, 2, 5, 6;
    2, 5, 6,     1;
    5, 6,     1, 1]
```

I tried using combinations of flip and toeplitz. I succeeded, but it got messy.

Comment: What you have is a Hankel matrix, but you need _two_ vectors to get this one, see [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the [hankel()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) function.

This works, but produces a warning:

```
A = hankel(a, ones(1,3))'
```

This is longer, but has no warnings:

```
A = hankel(a, [a(end) ones(1,2)])'
```

Andras Deak gave us the right answer in his comment.

Comment: To RJH : hankel of course. Would you please delight readers with the code you have used to answer your own question?

Comment: RJH thanks for adding the code answering your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=randi([-10 10],1,4)  % input 1D vector
A1=toeplitz(a);
A2=flip(A2,1);
A3=triu(toeplitz(A2)) + tril(ones(size(A2)),-1);
A3=flip(A3,1);
A3(end,:)=[]   % result
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Jeremy, sometimes adding explanations to simple short concise answers overcomplicate things. No need for further comment.